# Strapi v4 email sending plugin not working on live server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, smtp, strapi, nodemailer

I have setup a email sending plugin in ./config/plugins.js in my Strapi v4 setup like this:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    //...
    email: {
      config: {
        provider: 'nodemailer',
        providerOptions: {
          host: env('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
          port: env('SMTP_PORT', 465),
          secure: env('SMTP_SECURE',true),
          auth: {
            user: env('SMTP_USERNAME', 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'),
            pass: env('SMTP_PASSWORD', '*****************'),
          },
          pool: true,
          logger: true,
          debug: true,
          maxConnections: 10000
        },
        settings: {
          defaultFrom: 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
          defaultReplyTo: 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        },
      },
    },
    //...
  });
```

When I run an email sending test from the Admin panel, it works fine. However, when I deploy the build to my cPanel hosting, the email sending fails. What could I be doing wrong with this? Thanks for your assistance.